# How to make the font smaller in the overset?

Tags: fontsize

Consider the following excerpt:

[image]

The code is below:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
|\xi|\geq R&\pause\Rightarrow &|a(x, \xi)|\geq C|\xi|^m\\
&\pause\overset{|\xi|\geq 1, m\geq 0}\geq & \frac{C}{2^m}(1+|\xi|)^m\\
&\pause =& C (1+|\xi|)^m.
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Is there a way to make the code over the **\geq** (inside **\overset**) to look smaller?

I have tried the code **\tiny** but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: `\scriptscriptstyle` ?

Comment: I didn't knew of it, I'll check it out, thanks =)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that works =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LaTeX font sizes like `\tiny` can not be used in math mode however the Tex primitive commands `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle` are available to choose the size and style normally used in superscripts and superscripts of superscripts respectively. You probably want `\scriptscriptstyle` here.

Unrelated but `eqnarray` isn't the high point of the latex format. The `align` environment from `amsmath` is a lot better.

Comment: Thanks for the tips =) I use **eqnarry** only for getting the same spacing before and after all the equality (inequality) signs through the commands &=&. I guess that is not possible with **align** environment..

Comment: @Dion that's the point! the spacing used by `eqnarray` is _wrong_ and is based on the column spacing in `array` rather than the space that an infix `=` should have. using `align` and `x&=y` then `=` gets exactly the space it would have in `x=y`