# overbar with parenthesis

Tags: accents

I would like to have a decoration for math symbols that is a `\bar` - only with parenthesis around it. Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\barparen[1]{\overset{(-)}{#1}}
$p\bar{p}\barparen{p}$
\end{document}
```

Here's how it looks:

[image: first try]

Clearly, this is not very nice - the spacing is very different to the standard `\bar` command. Of course, I can try to fiddle with `\raisebox` and `\scalebox` until it looks about right, but isn't there some nicer way to do this?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286111/overlined-capital-letter-with-small-parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would recommend visiting [Overlined capital letter with small parenthesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286111/overlined-capital-letter-with-small-parenthesis).

Another way that I found from http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=6646 is to do the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\barparen[1]{\overset{(-)}{#1}}
$p\bar{p} \overset{\textbf{\fontsize{2pt}{2pt}\selectfont(---)}}{p} $\\
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions:

- Modify your macro `\barparen` by applying `\scriptscriptstyle` to the `(-)` thingy. (By default, the first argument of `\overset` is typeset in script style.)
- Use the `\scalebox` macro (part of the `graphicx` package) to reduce the size of the `(-)` thingy even further, and apply negative kerning (in the amount of `\mkern-1mu`) to snug up the `(`, `-`, and `)` elements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\barparena[1]{\overset{%
   \scriptscriptstyle(-)}{#1}}
\newcommand\barparenb[1]{\overset{%
   \scalebox{0.4}{$(\mkern-1mu-\mkern-1mu)$}}{#1}}
$p\bar{p}\barparena{p}\barparenb{p}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$ %
p % 
\overset{-}{p} %
\overset{(-)}{p} %
\overset{\scriptscriptstyle(-)}{p} %
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Related**

- [How to make the font smaller in the overset?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229377)